# Engel's elements of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Does the set of right Engel elements and the set of left Engel elements of any group $G$ are same?

Let $G$ be a group and $x_1, . . . , x_n ∈ G$. For all $n > 0 $ we define inductively $[x_1, . . . , x_n]$ as follows: $[x_1] = x_1$ and $[x_1, . . . , x_n] = [x_1, . . . , x_{n−1}]^{−1}x^{−1}_{n} [x_1, . . . , x_{n−1}]x_n$ for all $n>1$. If $x_2 =· · ·=x_n$, then we denote $[x_1, . . . , x_n]$ by $[x_1,_{n−1} x_2]$. Note that $[x_1] = [x_1,_0 x_2] = x_1$ and $[x_1, x_2] = x^{−1}_{1} x^{−1}_{2} x_1x_2$. An element $x$ of $G$ is called left Engel if for every element $a \in G$, there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $[a,_k x] = 1$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are "engel's elements"

Comment: A left engel element is also called engel element. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel_group.

Comment: There is a notion called "right engel element". See here http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927870903386460#.UqVk6iemrs0